# Разница между okhttp и retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

Доброго времени суток. Кто-нибудь может объяснить мне разницу между retrofit и okhttp? Ведь в okhttp строить запросы гораздо легче, на мной взгляд, тогда почему все используют retrofit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Retrofit` по сути это обертка для `OkHttp` или как привычно слышать API. 
И действительно это и есть REST API.

`OkHttp` - это клиент HTTP / SPDY.

Отсюда разница: 
Для OkHttp мы формируем URL, делаем запрос, получаем объект. А вот Retrofit генерирует URL, по уже заданным правилам и это действительно очень удобно. Всё что нужно это прописать интерфейс. После получения объекта в ретрофит можно использовать парсер(можно написать свой), который может сразу предоставить объект в нужном виде в колбеке для последующей работы, тоже удобно. Те по факту Retrofit всеравно использует okHttp, для того чтоб осуществить запрос, просто он дополнительно предоставляет дополнительный функционал и довольно удачно. 
По скорости работы всё будет идентично и это очевидно. А вот удобства для структуры очень много, Retrofit хорош для RxAndroid и удобно встает в Clean Architecture, удобно использовать в MVP, очень удобно выносится в модуль Dagger2. Да и сам Retrofit не ограничивает в теории настройку клиента OkHttp, вы можете его подменить.

Answer (score 9):

`okhttp` это библиотека, которая реализует связь по `http`. `Retrofit` это библиотека, которая даёт вам удобную работу с `REST` сервисами.

Объясняю: По умолчанию ретрофит базируется на `Okhttp`. Т.е. вам как разработчику, использующему ретрофит необходимо написать всего один интерфейс, и потом `Retrofit.Bulder()` сам сгенерирует для вас реализацию. Внутри сгенерированного класса вы увидите код работающий на `OkHttp`. Можно работать и без ретрофита, но тогда вместо написания одного интерфейса вам придется писать очень много лишнего кода.

Короче говоря, Ретрофит это обертка над `OkHttp` + куча разных крутых фишек, типа сериализаторов (к примеру Gson подключается одной строкой и все ваши `Java` классы магическим образом сериализуются/десериализуются в `JSON`) можно и в `XML`, еще из фишек - адаптеры, к примеру для RxJava и других хитрых библиотек, как упоминалось ранее - кодогенерация. Вы не пишете тонны кода, Ретрофит сгенерирует их за вас. Ну и прочие приятные фишки, которые вы откроете для себя плотно нырвнув в изучение ретрофита и `okhttp`

Answer (score 6):

`Retrofit` суть надстройка над `OkHttp`. Она помогает писать меньше кода для составления запросов к API и делать это в едином стандарте - вы в отдельном интерфейсе определяете `java` методы, указывая аннотациями тип `http` метода и его параметры - адрес, заголовки, поля, тело. Также вы определяете там тип возвращаемого значения - например класс-модель, в которую распарсится `json` ответ от сервера. После чего создаёте экземпляр класса, реализующий этот интерфейс (весь код уже готов) и просто вызываете описанный в интерфейсе метод - он вернёт ответ сервера в виде экземпляра `java` класса.

Как итог - меньше кода и всё собрано компактно в одном файле.